# React Router v6 shared layouts

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router

After reading [Route layouts](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes) I wanted to wrap some elements of my routes with a layout, but leave others without a layout.

Here is the example:

App.jsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<p>Home</p>} />

          <Route element={<div style={{ background: 'red' }} />}>
            <Route path="/login" element={<p>Login</p>} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
```

When I go to `/` I can see the text "Home", it has no layout.
But when I go to `/login` nothing renders, it should render the red background layout wrapping the text "Login".

Here is a live code sandbox:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-hwpla5?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/App.jsx

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

you have to render an `<Outlet />` for inside your layout element to specify where the active child route should be mounted.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<p>Home</p>} />
  <Route element={<div style={{ background: 'red' }} > <Outlet /> </div>}>
    <Route path="/login" element={<p>Login</p>} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. The example on https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes doesn't use outlet. Maybe I missunderstood.

Comment: @lcaruk I don't think you misunderstood. I been struggling myself with it till finally I found this thread. Apart from the missing explicit explanation on the `<Outlet />`, I think the docs also misleads the readers by stating the `<App />` will be rendered, while turns out it won't be.

Comment: Same here. This part of the doc is really bad. I should give an example of "Layout" component. I am thinking about finding another library. They have lost my trust

Comment: I find the answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69982280/9163798) as a good complement in order to understand the role of the `<Outlet />`

Comment: How is this not in the documentation? You'd really expect that your `PageLayout ` component needs to render children when reading the docs...