# Children won't render when using a layout in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using MUIv5 and React-Router v6 in my project, in which I want to wrap a layout around my pages, but the pages aren't rendering and all i'm getting is an empty div

This is my App component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { CssBaseline } from "@mui/material";

import MainLanding from './routes/MainLanding';
import StoreLanding from "./routes/StoreLanding";
import Layout from "./components/Layout";

const App = () =>{
    return(
        <>
            <CssBaseline/>
                <Routes>
                    <Route element={<Layout/>}>
                        <Route path="/" element={<MainLanding/>}/>
                        <Route path="/store" element={<StoreLanding/>}/>
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
        </>
    )
}

export default App
```

This is the layout component where i'm calling the children via props:

```
import React from 'react';

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}
export default Layout;
```

Output:
[image: empty div renders]

Comment: [Used this video as reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSuJLPRsdZQ&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gjxLvV4VEkZ6H6H4yWuS58&index=12)

Comment: why not wrap the routes in layout directly instead of wrapping it as an element in a route?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Router v6 shared layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70236929/react-router-v6-shared-layouts)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A layout component should render an `Outlet` for nested `Route` components to be rendered into. This is different from wrapper components that consume and render the `children` prop.

See [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) and [Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets) for more details.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes rendered here!
    </div>
  )
};
```

For comparison, wrapper components are used to wrap a child component in the `element` prop. Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/"
    element={(
      <Layout>
        <MainLanding />
      </Layout>
    )}
  />
  <Route
    path="/store"
    element={(
      <Layout>
        <StoreLanding />
      </Layout>
    )}
  />
</Routes>
```