# URL is being changed but component is not being rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In a project I'm working on, when I try to navigate by search bar from category page or categories page to product page, product component is being rendered successfully, but when I navigate from product page to another product page, URL is being changed as expected but nothing is being rendered. I tried changing version of `react-router-dom` to the latest one but it didn't work.

Here is my Route file :

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/home/categories">
      <Route path=":category" element={<category></category>}>
        <Route path=":product" element={<product></product>}></Route>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Here's search bar navigation component:

```
<NavLink to{`/home/categories/${product.category}/${product.id}`}>
  {product.name}
</NavLink>
```

Comment: Do you listen for param changes like `useParams`? It should rerender your page

Comment: Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] that includes all relevant code you are working with, e.g. this `category` and `product` components, so we can see what is or isn't rendered and why.

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/70852993/8690857

Comment: @Konrad , you mean using UseEffect() to render component whenever URL changes?

Comment: `useParams` should be enough, depending on what your component does. But your question is unclear

Comment: The `useParams` wouldn't come into play until ***after*** you get the component mounting/rendering issue resolved, and this is only to "react" to the route path parameters changing. We can't see what these components are rendering though so we can't address any specific issue(s) they may have.

Answer (score -1):

You have same paths `:category` and `:product`. They are dynamic parameters, they are not the path

Whatever goes after `/home/categories/...` will be matched with the first Route and that is     `<Route path=':category' element={<category></category>>`

If you want paths `/home/categories/category` and `/home/categories/product`, remove the `:` symbol in front of the nested paths

Comment: I think op wanted `categories/:category/:product`

Comment: thank you for answering, but in my project they should be dynamic