# Redirect user from the dashboard page to login page when user click on logout button

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Hi I have a user dashboard in which I'm showing some basic details of the users, and I have also given a logout button so onces user click on it he/she should be completely redirect to the login page, but the proble is when I'm trying to access the login page then by default the dashboard is also getting loaded.

I'm not sure where I have to add the login module into App.js

```
function App() {
return (
<Router>
<div className="App">
  <Topbar/>
  <div className='container'>
  <Sidebar/>
  <div className='others'>
  
  <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
      <Route path="/createTrip" element={<CreateTrip/>} />
      <Route path="/allTrip" element={<AllTrip/>} />
      <Route path="/driverDetail" element={<DriverDetails/>} />
      <Route path="/myVehicle" element={<MyVehicle/>} />
  <Route path="*" element={<Home />} />
  </Routes>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  </div>
</Router>
```

);
}

[image]

Comment: Create a layout and add everypage to that layout except login. Add login and other page to normal layout that you want. And then you can redirect however you want (either via guard or directly redirect and log user out)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70236929/react-router-v6-shared-layouts

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding of your question, You want to redirect to login page once you click on logout, but instead your dashboard is rendered.

The approximation of your problem is redirection, private routing and session handling.

If you are handling user sessions (holding user login state in localStorage or in your app state), use private routes to check weather the user is logged in or not and accordingly redirect to the desired page.

In your example it would be similar to adding nested routes with private route as their parent.

> Private Route -

```
import Navigate from "react-router-dom";
    export const PrivateRoute =({children}) => {
       if(localStorage.getItem("token")){
    return children
           } else {
                Navigate("/login")
           }
    
     }




        function App() {
    return (
    <Router>
    <div className="App">
      <Topbar/>
      <div className='container'>
      <Sidebar/>
      <div className='others'>
      
      <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
          <Route path="/createTrip" element={<PrivateRoute><CreateTrip/></PrivateRoute>} />
          <Route path="/allTrip" element={<PrivateRoute><AllTrip/></PrivateRoute>} />
          // and so on
      </Routes>
      </div>
      </div>

      
      </div>

</Router>
```